# how to respond to a client request in ios using a script php containing a stream video using movieplayer? here is my code

Tags: php, ios, streaming, response, movieplayer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *stream = @"file://localhost/Users/mac-01/Desktop/php_ios.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];
    MoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:MoviePlayer];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *res = nil;
    NSData *retData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&res error:&err];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:retData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (err)     {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
        [MoviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 300, 150)];
        [self.view addSubview:MoviePlayer.view];
        MoviePlayer.fullscreen= YES;
        MoviePlayer.allowsAirPlay= YES;
        MoviePlayer.shouldAutoplay= YES;
        MoviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        MoviePlayer.controlStyle= MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        MoviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
        [MoviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [MoviePlayer play]; 
    }
}


- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];    
    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the URL you are calling .php file but not with movie extension file`file://localhost/Users/mac-01/Desktop/php_ios.php`

Better way to call this URL using the Json format then do the Json parsing and then load the video URL to play on MoviePlayer

Check this Answer hope it will help you to solve [How to play a video with MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194776/how-to-play-a-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller?rq=1)

Comment: How can i use Json in streaming a video?

Comment: <?php

$handle = fopen("http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v, http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/", "rb");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
     $contents .=fread($handle, 80);
}

fclose($handle);

$fp = fopen("$Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v", "wb");
fwrite($fp, $contents);
fclose($fp);
?>

Comment: json will not use to streaming you video it just load the particular files in an array from you php file like this I do this to load Images      json result (
        {
        image = "http://localhost/image/theme/1.png";
        sno = 1;
    },
        {
        image = "http://localhost/image/theme/2.png";
        sno = 2;
    },
        {
        image = "http://img.gismeteo.ru/images/icon";
        sno = 3;
    }
)

Comment: How can i do this without Json? is there is any changes to make in ios   or in a php to make it work?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do without Json but I suggest you load name file **file://localhost/Users/mac-01/Desktop/php_ios.php** and add video name to the link and check if loads.