# Is there any proper solution for error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800 and -11819 with MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using MPMoviePlayerViewController to play video files in my iOS App. When I played video from server URL

then I am getting error :

> "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800"

and when i am playing video from Local Storage Then i am getting error :

> "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11819".

One specific scenario about this problem is that first time I got that error and second time it played successfully and this problem I can reproduce everytime. Can you guys please provide me proper solution?

Below is the code OP is using.

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController * controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 
controller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeFile; 
[controller.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[controller.moviePlayer play];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
```

Comment: Please fix your post's formatting, that looks terrible. Use the `` characters to highlight your code (just put one on each side of your code)

Comment: @Dakkaron Sorry for that i am not aware about these things. But my i am not getting the proper solution for this problem. Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: As I said, fix your post before you want answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play a video with MPMoviePlayerController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194776/how-to-play-a-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller)

Comment: Ok, that's better. Now have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194776/how-to-play-a-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller That seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Dakkaron Is it correct now?

Comment: @Dakkaron I tried with .mp4 and .mov files from my NSBundle and also from server. These links are not helpful for me.

Comment: show me your code... I know where is issue...

Comment: @FahimParkar
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController * controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:fileURL];
controller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[controller.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[controller.moviePlayer play];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];

Comment: all videos on my server in mp4 format , i have given a sample URL. This is not the URL of my server but same problem i have with this URL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at below line.

```
controller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
```

You are playing online video and telling that this is normal file (which is locally)

Please comment above line and let me know how it goes.

Below is the code that works with me.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
    @"http://www.example.com/video.mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
    initWithContentURL:url];

self.mc = controller; //Super important
controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds; //Set the size

[self.view addSubview:controller.view]; //Show the view
[controller play]; //Start playing
```

Comment: I commented the movieSourceType but still i am getting error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11819. I also tried to play video  from NSBundle but same error occurred.

Comment: @user1755630 : give me the url of the video.. I will check the problem and let you know

Comment: please use this url
https://www.urduspace.com/musicmuseum/upload/Video/141%20-%20Tubanio.mp4

Comment: @user1755630 : use the code that I provide and let me know whether it is working or not...

Comment: My url is not working with code which you provided, but it is working on browser properly.

Comment: @user1755630 : ohhk, check another some sample video... don't use yours, use another...

Comment: It plays video for few second and then i got the Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11819.